# Why does JavaScript cut zeros?

Tags: javascript, string, number-formatting

I have a simple function to add zeros before numbers:

```
function validateString(length, str){
    var newStr = '' + str;
       for (var i = str.length; i < length; i++)
          newStr = '0' + newStr;
    return newStr;
}
```

What do I need to change (types of variables?) to make it works for the numbers too?

```
validateString(12,2);
"2" // Unexpected rezult
validateString(12,'2');
"000000000002"
```

Comment: Your expected result is `000000000002`?

Comment: A number can never start with 0, that's why you have to use a string.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is happening because you're calling `str.length` and not `newStr.length`. Number values have an *undefined* length.

Change:

```
for (var i = str.length; i < length; i++)
```

To:

```
for (var i = newStr.length; i < length; i++)
```

---

```js
function validateString(length, str){
    var newStr = '' + str;
       for (var i = newStr.length; i < length; i++)
          newStr = '0' + newStr;
    return newStr;
}

console.log(validateString(12,2));
console.log(validateString(12,'2'));
```

Comment: Thank you very much